# How to play a midi file in html

Tags: html, midi

how can I play a midi file in my html/php page

Right now I surf the net and got lots of simple embed code like the one I given below

```
<EMBED SRC="C:\Windows\Media\Onestop.mid" hidden=true autostart=true loop=1>
```

But my firefox says to install plugin - Quicktime player

I don't think this is the way or how to bypass this above said issue, may be if you can suggest another method to do this if any.

Comment: you have to.... install plugin there is no choice..

Comment: PHP doesn't play files. It's merely a string processor. Corrected tags.

Comment: Does it have to be a midi file? The common format on the Web is MP3, which you can embed easily using HTML 5 or Flash-based players. Consider recording the Midi into a MP3 file

Comment: yes I want in the website the option to play midi incase there is not mp3 file for the same sound-records

Comment: The mid-1990s called; they want their _bleedin' irritating_ websites back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no cross-browser way to do this: Flash, the most common option when embedding audio on a web page, [doesn't play Midi files](http://forums.adobe.com/message/198587).

The only way is indeed the `embed` method, and whether that works will depend on how the user's browser is set up. A plug-in (like Quicktime) will have to be installed that can handle the file.  If the "install plugin" dialog appears on a computer, it won't work there.

I think the only sane way is to convert those Midis to MP3 files.

Comment: is there a way to invoke the windows media player in windows to open this midi file and in apple/mac the quicktime

Comment: @Rahul if the browser is set up accordingly, that will happen automatically with the code you show above. There is no other way to invoke a client side program to play the file.

Answer (score 11):

I know it's been a while, but this is top of Google for "website midi player", so I thought I'd drop in a solution.

I made a website and wanted to play a midi file, and there's a Javascript plugin you can use: http://www.midijs.net/

Just include the library:
`<script src='http://www.midijs.net/lib/midi.js'></script>`

And then the file you want to play: `<script>MIDIjs.play('path/to.your/file.mid');</script>`

**Important edit**
It seems that the remote file is doing Crypto mining, which is less than ideal. You should either store the file locally and remove `t("https://coinhive.com/lib/coinhive.min.js",D)`, or use the original code from GitHub: https://github.com/babelsberg/babelsberg-js/tree/master/midijs

Thanks to @David de Kleer for pointing that out.

Comment: that's a nice plugin. To get it to work I had to modify it slightly, slipping in `midijs_url = "http://www.midijs.net/lib/";` because the URL detection fails. Otherwise works great on all but iOS and IE.

Comment: I am currently using this plugin in a MIDI file generation hobby project, but my CPU usage went almost through the roof! I checked out the minified code, and it turned out there is a cryptocurrency miner hidden in it, which really surprised me! (Check out [this](http://www.midijs.net/lib/midi.js) and see the `new CoinHive.Anonymous` part) Turns out they are using [this](https://github.com/babelsberg/babelsberg-js/tree/master/midijs) for the MIDI generation, you can also check that out, or just remove the `t("https://coinhive.com/lib/coinhive.min.js",D)` part and host it yourself.

Comment: @DaviddeKleer Well spotted! They weren't doing that a couple of years ago. The buggers.

Comment: When this library is used, it currently throws an error: The AudioContext was not allowed to start. It must be resumed (or created) after a user gesture on the page.

Comment: That error is caused by Chrome @BrianEllis as Chrome (or likely whatever browser you are using) has an anti-autoplay feature which requires users to click somewhere or do something on a page before audio can be played. I know it's a bit late, but adding a button or something like that which then triggers this code is the solution to your problem.

Answer (score 5):

With [html-midi-player](https://github.com/cifkao/html-midi-player), it is possible to embed a MIDI file in a website simply by inserting a `midi-player` element (a custom HTML element which works a lot like the `audio` element, but for MIDI files):

```html
<midi-player src="jazz.mid" sound-font></midi-player>
```

Complete demo:

```html
<midi-player src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/cifkao/html-midi-player@2b12128/jazz.mid" sound-font>
</midi-player>

<!-- The following needs to be inserted somewhere on the page for the player(s) to work. -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/combine/npm/tone@14.7.58,npm/@magenta/music@1.22.1/es6/core.js,npm/focus-visible@5,npm/html-midi-player@1.4.0"></script>
```

*Full disclosure: I'm the author of html-midi-player.*

The playback functionality is provided by Google's [Magenta.js](https://github.com/magenta/magenta-js/) library. It's also possible to use Magenta.js directly to play MIDI files, but this requires a non-trivial amount of JavaScript coding, which is why I created html-midi-player.

Comment: Very nice - just what I was looking for. And no bitcoin miner... Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Use Web Audio API for modern browsers. See complete [example of player](https://surikov.github.io/webaudiofont/examples/midiplayer.html). It works on desktop and mobile.

Answer (score 1):

Java can play MIDI files, and the necessary plugin is installed (in the factory) on most PCs

Incomplete examples [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/453627/Applets/java/MID-player-applet) and [here](http://www.harfesoft.de/aixphysik/sound/HFPlayer/Doc/index.html)

Comment: +1 for a solution - although firing up Java to play a music file feels like *massive* overkill